# Rails: Why does create/update action point to the same URL like the index action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes, put, restful-architecture

When creating or updating a resource, the target URL by default is the same like the index route, for users e.g. `localhost:3000/users`.

The difference is that instead of `POST`, `PUT` method is used (as far as I know).

I find this suboptimal. For example, when having a navigation menu with an item "Create user" in it, I want to set the `active` CSS class when the item is active. I do this by comparing `current_page?` to the menu item's URL (e.g. `users/new`). This works fine, but only when I don't have validation errors. In this case, the URL now isn't `users/new` anymore, but `users`.

Is there a good reason why Rails doesn't point to `users/new` (or `users/edit`) respectively for POST/PUT requests? Are there any downsides to using them? Is there an easy way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Well, from experience I can tell you that it is not such a good idea to fight the framework with this.

Comment: Yes, I also prefer having post-backs to the same URL for the new/create and edit/update pairs. It is not hard to do this (see answers below) but you might end up doing a lot of work to keep url and form helpers functioning properly. Rather than that your time might be better spent creating more resilient CSS. I recommend avoiding page- or url-specific styles. In my experience they are not maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

In a nutshell, Rails treats everything as a resource, and there are conventions followed in order to do so. In a typical CRUD application, you have the Create (POST), Read (GET), Update (PUT/PATCH), and Destroy (DELETE) actions, which are the verbs used to act on resources.

Let's say you have a User resource. A list of users would be found at `/users`. An individual user, being an individual object of a resource, would then be found at `/users/1`, where "1" is the identifier of the resource in question.

Now, based on the CRUD verbs available to you, if you wanted to edit a user, what ACTION makes the most sense given the CRUD verbs we talked about? PUT `/users/1` is the correct answer; you're updating (the U in CRUD) a particular resource. If you wanted to delete that user? DELETE `/users/1` makes sense. If you want to create one? CREATE `/users` is the logical choice, because you're not acting on a particular object, but on the resource as a whole, similar to GET `/users` not acting on an individual object, but a collection.

`/users/new` is a path to a page that will let you do that, but it doesn't mean it should make the CREATE request to /users/new, because "new" doesn't describe a resource the same way.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that it's written down like that in theory. From a pragmatic side, I would have preferred they decided it the other way